# Use jsTree as folder browser

Tags: c#, javascript, datasource, jstree

I would like to use jsTree as a folder browser.
I have got a folder(root) and inside this folder there are a lot of folders.
What do I want? I want to tell jsTree the path os this folder and in code behind(c# or Javascript) load all the folders in jsTree.
I can do this with JSON(http://www.jstree.com/docs/json/), but I think it is not a good idea, because there are 200 folders.
Is there any option?

Thanks.

Comment: Why isn't JSON a good idea? JSON can cope quite easily with 200 objects. If you, for some reason, have a concern about the size of JSON then you can make AJAX requests for sub-folders on the necessary 'opening' (?) events of the parent folders. But that also has it's implications. I recommend you stick to the documentation in this case.

Comment: Imagine that a new folder is added to the structure, then I must change the code, otherwise, If I tell to jsTree the path, If any folder is added, it will change automatically.

Comment: Right, I didn't realise you meant you want the JavaScript to respond to server-side events (new folders created). You'll have to survey the folder structure at regular intervals (server-side obviously) and then convey any changes to the front-end using technology such as SignalR (which will then, ultimately, return (or 'push') JSON anyway to drive your JSTree). Either way it's JSON, but due to the complexity of your task you won't get the answer here unless you break it down further into more specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the compressed jQuery script. It has a size of 84KB.

If you assume 200 Bytes for one folder entry (which is not that short), you could transport 430 folders as one JSON to have the same load. JSON was designed to be lightweight and short, to me it is the right choice. If you consider XML, you would have maybe a quota full text / payload of factor 1.5 to 2.2.

I wouldn't worry about 84KB, you won't feel them. So I wouldn't worry about 200 folders. First try to implement the mechanism, and optimize later, if necessary.

Later, a possible optimization could consist of:

- Pure visual help: adding a spinner that explains the user that something is going on, may significantly rise the user's acceptance.
- Compressing your JSON
- Load in pieces: Send the first half first, while the user navigates load the second half.